# List of badges offered much later after feat is performed

Tags: support, badges, badge-tracking

My experience tells me that there are certain badges which are awarded instantaneously after a feat is achieved. Whereas, there are some which are offered, say an hour or more later, after the moment the feat is completed. Can someone give me a list of those? Just for info...

Comment: Tag badges are awarded at around 3 UTC only.

Comment: @quid Is there an exhaustive list?

Comment: I would not know about one. The rule of thumb is that the more transversal information a tag needs the longer it takes (rare ones might also have lower priority).  Something completely localized to the post, like nice answer, is near instant, yet enlightened can take a short while  (as it depends on other answers). More complex or rare things could take still longer.